# Set DataGridView SelectedRows after Update

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, selecteditem

In one of my C# Winform, I have a DataGridView that I update when the user presses a refresh button.

The problem is that the selected row is lost in the process.

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
private void function Refresh()
{
UpdateBegin(); // Keep the selected row in memory
Update();
UpdateEnd(); // Apply the selected row to the DataGridView
}
```

Here is the Update function. It updates the data source, clears all the columns and bring back those that are required with the proper header text:

```
private void Update()
{
    allItem = DataRepository.LotProvider.GetByIdProduit(detail.IdProduit)
dataGridView1.DataSource = allItem;
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
// Get a dictionary of the required column ID / shown text
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = InitDisplayedFields();        
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> column in dictionary)
    // If the grid does not contain the key
    if (!dataGridView1.Columns.Contains(column.Key))
    {
        // Add the column (key-value)
        int id = dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column.Key, column.Value);
        // Bind the property
        dataGridView1.Columns[id].DataPropertyName = column.Key;
    }

}
```

However, the selected rows property of my DataGridView is Read-only.

Is there a workaround to this ?

Comment: Could you tell us more about what your Update does? Does it clear all the rows, then pull the latest from a database somewhere? The reason I ask is, you should be able to add and remove rows without altering the selection, unless you remove part of the selection. In that case, I believe the selection is only altered by what you removed.

Comment: The Update function gets and updated data source, clears the dataGrid and brings back the required column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like the following excerpt from MSDN ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.selected.aspx)) on this topic:

```
void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

Second line in this code snippet shows how to programmatically select the row, provided that you keep track of the selected `RowIndex` (as it's probably done in your `UpdateBegin()` function call).

Hope this could help.

Comment: `this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, it should work. There is another option of using GridView.DataKeys, but this one probably will suffice.